postfix now very slow to send or recieve if it even does
We have a very old postfix/mail server (we are trying to upgrade it /retire/goto the cloud) but before we get to any of this it started to act bizarre the last few days.
I thought it was because the data drive it stores all users email on was getting full, like very full.  Courier IMAP is used, I finally figured out why it was full.
One user is moving a ton of emails in their macmail client around, organizing them if you well, but it is like thousands of emails, and that for a time sucked up space on mail server doing that, and resources.  The space now days later has gotten better "only" at 90% full, but doing an htop I still see this constantly sucking up high CPU:
(actually this is top because I cannot copy past htop)
8361 postfix   20   0   44856  23256   1516 S  12.6  0.4   1:12.30 imapd
19729 postfix   20   0   27028   5528   1496 D   5.6  0.1   0:44.89 imapd
21777 postfix   20   0   27028   5504   1488 D   5.0  0.1   0:17.70 imapd
22467 postfix   20   0   27028   5512   1488 D   4.6  0.1   0:07.83 imapd
19962 postfix   20   0   30304   8808   1504 D   4.3  0.1   0:40.11 imapd
18377 postfix   20   0   27460   5868   1512 D   4.0  0.1   1:11.75 imapd
21758 postfix   20   0   30808   9308   1500 D   3.6  0.2   0:16.77 imapd
19410 postfix   20   0   27028   5516   1488 D   3.0  0.1   0:53.53 imapd

These are all the same users, and the CPU usage on the top end can go very high like 30% and its constant.  I cannot tell what is going on.  I know this is the user moving stuff around but that was started 2 weeks ago!  Surely that should be settled down, not sure if their mailbox is in a bad state or what not.
postconf mail_version
mail_version = 2.10.1

I mean while never fun to work with this server has ran okay over the years (I didn't set it up and keep trying to get everyone on board to move to the cloud event hough I have no idea how to do that with our mailman servers too)...so we are stuck old servers and I have zero postfix knowledge.
So not sure where to start looking into this, that one user on this server is taking up a ton of CPU that seems odd, the command according to htop is:  imapd ourfolder/thisuser@ourmailserver/
When I do an HTOP I see something akin to this:
PID USER PRI NI VIRT RES SHR S CPU% MEM% TIME+ Command
22481 postfix 20 0 27450 5508 D 9.8% 0.1  0:28:52 imapd ourfolder/thisuser@ourmailserver/
20465 postfix 20 0 27450 5508 D 6.6% 0.1  0:28:52 imapd ourfolder/thisuser@ourmailserver/
20314 postfix 20 0 27450 5508 D 5.2% 0.1  0:28:52 imapd ourfolder/thisuser@ourmailserver/
19045 postfix 20 0 27450 5508 D 4.3% 0.1  0:28:52 imapd ourfolder/thisuser@ourmailserver/
20734 postfix 20 0 27450 5508 D 1.4% 0.1  0:28:52 imapd ourfolder/thisuser@ourmailserver/

and that list will be about 8-10 lines long, all the same user, all different PID all taking some version of a fair amount of CPU$ sometimes as high as 30% and the mem% is always pretty low but sometimes jumps to more.
Not sure if any logs would help investigate why it is slow, or why I have to generally reboot the server to get mail flowing again for a while.  Had problems start two weeks ago, thought it was due to low space, cleared space, took off the veeam agent running on server and things seemed 'okay' over the holiday break when most were not using mail, as soon as 8am rolled around this morning that same one user was going nuts in htop again and the server was back to running like crap.
Again reboots help get mail flowing for a bit then it degrades to the same schtick.
Did check incoming connections to mail server to make sure it wasnt some sort of denial attack, it didn't seem to be.  Also saw the only log I could find:
/var/log/maillog which didn't have anything different form other times I have seen that file to my knowledge.
So I am not sure what to look at next why our mail server runs super slow all of a sudden (especially confused now that there is 10% space recovered on data drive) also not sure if it was that move command in a client (macmail I think) for that users which now 2 weeks later still has a ton of processes in htop going on.   This server is actually a VM running on an old machine under KVM wondering if I could just give it more resources to fix things?  but that would be guessing and hoping something sticks without understanding the main cause.

Your title is a bit confusing - it says Postfix, but then you're talking about Courier IMAP.. Although it looks like your imapd is running as user postfix, which must be some kind of misconfiguration. Do you know the "offendiing" user in question? Is it acceptable to just lock their account temporarily, reboot, and then see if the issue persists without that user moving around mails? I'm not at all sure that this is the real problem, since if this was a disk bottleneck, your imapd wouldn't be using 30% CPU. It would be waiting on the I/O (category waiting at the top of top)

Courier might have been made to run the same user as Postfix just to simplify configuration. // I'm having some deja vu with this question. I vaguely remember I've seen the question here about disk performance and Courier not long ago.
